# UITableView Cells - How to make one cell's height fixed, other cell's height variable relative to screen size?

Tags: ios, swift, height, uitableview

I have a static UITableView with 1 section, 2 cells.

I would like the 'bottom' cell to be of fixed height 70 pixels and the 'top' cell of variable height - to fill the balance of screen. As follows:

[image]

I hav this code:

```
//Modify TableView Cell Heights For Screen Sizes:
var absoluteCellHeights: [CGFloat] = [300, 70] {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

var normalisedCellHeights: [CGFloat]? {
    let totalHeight = absoluteCellHeights.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
    let normalisedHeights: [CGFloat]? = totalHeight <= 0 ? nil : absoluteCellHeights.map { $0 / totalHeight }

    return normalisedHeights
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let height: CGFloat


    if let normalisedHeight = self.normalisedCellHeights?[indexPath.row] {
        height = normalisedHeight * tableView.frame.height
    } else {
        height = 50.0 // Just a random value.
    }

    return height
}
```

... which works fine on my smallest screen size target (3.5 inch) where I have a total size allocation for both cells of 370 pixels.

But for larger screen sizes, my total size allocation increases. And with the above code, both cells will be displayed on a 300:70 relative ratio.

I want the size of the top cell to be variable to screen sizes - larger the screen, the greater the cell height. But the size of the bottom cell to remain a constant of 70 pixels.

Can someone please assist? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: why are you using a table view instead of just 2 views with a couple of layout constraints?

Comment: That's a very good question. Essentially I have a series of different TableViewControllers - some with 2 cells, some with more. But the bottom cell is always of constant height.

Comment: ^Also agreed. If your table view isn't dynamic, just use two views, one with a height constraint of 70 and the other pinned to the remaining edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instinct is correct, you want to use `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 1 { return 70 }
    else { return tableView.frame.size.height - 70 }
}
```

If that doesn't work, comment with what went wrong and I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Ahh. So much more simple ;) That would by default essentially return any other cell of row != 1 to fill the balance of the screen? I'll try it and report back.

Comment: If you have more than two cells though, you can simply change the check to : `if indexPath.row == self.data.count - 1` where `data` is an array of the date you're providing to the table view.

Comment: Fabulous logic. Deserving of a ribbon and bow ;) Thanks so much. Perfect for my needs!

Comment: I would recommend though using autolayout with simple views if your table view content isn't dynamic unless you need the look and feel that comes with a table view.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little? I will adopt the two (2) UIViews with a couple of layout constraints strategy (thanks @Wain) for all my TableViewControllers that currently contain two (2) tableview cells - makes it simpler for me. But is there another reason?

Comment: It means you don't have to use table views or any related code setting up those views and sizes. You can do all that in interface builder instead of calculating heights in the table view delegate/datasource. The main reason is if you're not using dynamic data and you don't need the table view ui, then it's simpler to have two views with autolayout constraints, not confined to a table view.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    var height: CGFloat

    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        height = 70.0
    } else {
        height = tableView.frame.height - 70.0
    }

    return height
}
```